# How to get last N rows RELATIVE to another row in pandas (vector solution)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've asked this question in the context of another longer one, but I think I tried to ask too many things at once.  So, for simplicity:

I have a data frame where a key is pressed every trial.  I want to add a column that shows the last N rows.  So if my data looks like this:

```
trial sid  key_pressed        RT  
1     S04            x  0.502242        
2     S04            m  0.348620      
3     S04            m  0.312491       
4     S04            x  0.342541      
5     S04            n  0.419384       
6     S04            n  0.348211      
7     S04            z  0.376369
```

afterward it would look like this (for every individual sid):

```
trial sid  key_pressed        RT           last_3
1     S04            x  0.502242        NaN
2     S04            m  0.348620        NaN
3     S04            m  0.312491        [x, m, m]
4     S04            x  0.342541        [m, m, x]
5     S04            n  0.419384        [m, x, n]
6     S04            n  0.348211        [x, n, n]
7     S04            z  0.376369        [n, n, z]
```

Is there a vectorized solution to this?  I can't seem to figure out how to select relative rows.  (New to pandas - not great at thinking this way, yet)

UPDATE:  Based on advice from contributors below, I wound up doing this:

```
df['shifted'] = pd.concat([df.groupby('sid')['key_pressed'].shift(2) + df.groupby('sid')['key_pressed'].shift(1) + df.groupby('sid')['key_pressed'].shift(0)])
```

which created a string `mxm`, for example. Which is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `shift` to move the relevant column down `n` rows and then concatenate the entries (they are strings so we can use `+`):

```
df.last_3 = df.key_pressed.shift(1) + ', ' + df.key_pressed.shift(2) + ', ' + df.key_pressed.shift(3)
```

This creates strings of the previous three entries separated by a comma and space (not lists). I'd avoid using lists in DataFrames if possible as things can get a little messy.

Comment: thanks - i like shift.  and yes, i agree it is better not to have lists. (Though I'm realizing this only now)

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do with those lists? Storing lists inside Series/DataFrames is not usually very convenient. Anyway, this would get you close. You have to handle the `nans`, and then you're done.

```
In [6]: pd.concat([df.key_pressed.shift(i) for i in [0, 1, 2]], 1).apply(tuple, 1).map(list)
Out[6]: 
0    [x, nan, nan]
1      [m, x, nan]
2        [m, m, x]
3        [x, m, m]
4        [n, x, m]
5        [n, n, x]
6        [z, n, n]
dtype: object
```

Notice that we have to convert to a tuple and then a list, to avoid pandas automatically taking our list and making it back into a Series. Try this and you'll see why it doesn't work:

```
pd.concat([df.key_pressed.shift(i) for i in [0, 1, 2]], 1).apply(list, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks - good point about storing lists.  I'll take that into account and just create strings.  What I want to do is check whether the list is part of another column.  Now that you've brought it up, strings are way easier, anyway.  Basically I'll be checking whether ```zn``` is part of ```mznxm``` (so, ```True```).  But ```nz``` should yield ```False```

Answer (score 0):

Oh - perhaps this is the best solution.  One can "shift" the data by a certain amount:

```
df['shifted'] = df.groupby('sid')['key_pressed'].shift(2)
```

Then I could create lists from this shifted data.

Answer (score 0):

This solution avoids looping, but I'm not sure whether it really counts as 'vectorized', since once you start using `apply()` I think you start losing any performance benefits granted by vectorization:

```
key_table = pd.concat(
    [df.key_pressed.shift(2), df.key_pressed.shift(1), df.key_pressed], 
    axis=1
)
 df['last_3'] = key_table.apply(
    lambda row: ', '.join(str(k) for k in row),
    axis=1
)
```

Output:

```
   trial  sid key_pressed        RT       last_3
0      1  S04           x  0.502242  nan, nan, x
1      2  S04           m  0.348620    nan, x, m
2      3  S04           m  0.312491      x, m, m
3      4  S04           x  0.342541      m, m, x
4      5  S04           n  0.419384      m, x, n
5      6  S04           n  0.348211      x, n, n
6      7  S04           z  0.376369      n, n, z
```